# Convert \pdfcreationdate to pdfa-1b pdfinfo

Tags: pdftex, date, pdf-a

I am using usual method to prepare `pdfinfo` with date conversion:

```
\def\convertDate{%
    \getYear
}

{\catcode`\D=12
 \gdef\getYear D:#1#2#3#4{\edef\xYear{#1#2#3#4}\getMonth}
}
\def\getMonth#1#2{\edef\xMonth{#1#2}\getDay}
\def\getDay#1#2{\edef\xDay{#1#2}\getHour}
\def\getHour#1#2{\edef\xHour{#1#2}\getMin}
\def\getMin#1#2{\edef\xMin{#1#2}\getSec}
\def\getSec#1#2{\edef\xSec{#1#2}\getTZh}
\def\getTZh +#1#2{\edef\xTZh{#1#2}\getTZm}
\def\getTZm '#1#2'{%
    \edef\xTZm{#1#2}%
    \edef\convDate{\xYear-\xMonth-\xDay T\xHour:\xMin:\xSec+\xTZh:\xTZm}%
}

\expandafter\convertDate\pdfcreationdate
```

However this doesn't work for me. I am using Overleaf with pdfLaTeX compiler.

Error is

```
Use of \getTZh doesn't match its definition.

<inserted text> D:20190304112428Z

l.155 \expandafter\convertDate\pdfcreationdate
```

I am guessing it has to do with the "Z" at the end. But why is "Z" there? There should be +01'00' there.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out just after posting the question. Overleaf needs the time zone set. [This](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Set_Time_Zone) is an example.

It works now.